# Span element with fontawesome icon class in Jquery script automatically replaced by SVG ? Strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome-5

I'm doing this in a jquery module:

```
$('#myId').find("li.myClass").each(function () {
                var rightNavButton = $("<span/>", {"class": "right fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"});
                myButton.prependTo($(this));
            });
```

my html5 output dissappoints me with an SVG and out-commented SPAN :

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-right fa-w-16 right" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="arrow-alt-circle-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8c137 0 248 111 248 248S393 504 256 504 8 393 8 256 119 8 256 8zM140 300h116v70.9c0 10.7 13 16.1 20.5 8.5l114.3-114.9c4.7-4.7 4.7-12.2 0-16.9l-114.3-115c-7.6-7.6-20.5-2.2-20.5 8.5V212H140c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v64c0 6.6 5.4 12 12 12z"></path></svg>
<!-- <span class="right fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></span> -->
```

Why does it happen? I searched for information about replacing functions inside of font-awesome, but didn't found anything yet. Is this behaviiour normal? What am I missing?

The javascript is included on page bottom,
the css in page head.
All dists are up to date and the order is correct.

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use *remember that Font Awesome-based `<i>` DOM elements are replaced with new `<svg>` elements by default*

Comment: I need this in a span. How may I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/jquery

You can protect the replacement of Span tags and let the icon embbed into the tags, for the reason that you can use events on the span or other tags.

Nice to know the trick